# Which statistics to be use for comparison?

Tags: regression, correlation

I want to compare pre and post therapy scores of one test (continuous variable) with pre and post therapy scores of other test (the values are on a seven point rating scale).

---

I had measured some processing skills in a set of 16 pathological cases. The measurement was in terms of dB and Hz (continuous scale). Then I measured the annoyance caused by that pathology in a 7 point scale. These both were considered as pre treatment scores. Afterthat the patients undergone a set of therapy for 1 year, and all the measurements were carried out again at 1 month, 3 month, 6 month and 12 month and considered as post treatment scores. Now I did pre and post treatment statistics for processing skills using repeated measures ANOVA. A comparison between pre and post treatment annoyance scored were also carried out using repeated measures (I am not sure whether this is correct). Finally I want to show some association that improves processing skills resulted in reduced annoyance level.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain in details of your data, assumptions, sample size ...etc.

In the case of a 7 point Likert scale, you can use a multinomial logistic regression or a ordinal logistic regression to check for difference between scores.

If you are comparing pre and post scores, it would be a repeated measure study, please elaborate so you can know whether to use a z or t test to analyze the data.